# How to setup the Oculus Rift using a MSI trident computer?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, oculus-rift

### Problem

I've installed a new MSI Trident 007EU computer and will now like to setup an Oculus Rift. I've found a [full users manual guide](https://www.manualscat.com/sv/msi-trident-007eu-manual) online. I connected the back HDMI ports with each other like on image below.

[image]

In the front HMDI port, I connected the HDMI port of the Oculus Rift. There is one port remaining on the back side and I will use that for my monitor but there is no signal there.

### Overview

On the back side, the HDMI ports are numbered 5, 7 and 9. Number 6 is a DVI-D port.

[image]

On the front side, number 6 is a HDMI port

[image]

To use the front HDMI port, you must connect HDMI ports 5 and 7 on the back side.

### Question

How can I use my monitor at the same time with the Oculus Rift? [On MSI's website](https://www.msi.com/Desktop/Trident.html#hero-overview) it says it's VR ready, but it seems like it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the DVI port to connect that with my monitor and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI(9) is connected to the Internal Graphics, and when you install a graphics card, it gets disabled.

So for the monitor you can use the DVI as you did, or the Display port.

How did you plug the USBs ?